# Is there an interface that is similar to CrudRepository that allows to return Optional<T> find()?

Tags: java, spring-boot

My current code uses

```
@Repository
public interface PlayersRepository extends CrudRepository<Player, Long> {
    Page<Player> findAll();
    Optional<Player> findById(Long id);
}
```

and I want to add

```
Optional<Player> find();
```

instead.

Is there such an interface under `org.springframework.stereotype`?

Comment: What version of Spring Data JPA are you using? `CrudRepository` [already](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html) has that, but I do know it was not available in some older version.

Comment: @x80486 could you link me to that method? I can't find `Optional<T> find()` under `All methods` section.

Comment: Ah! You won't! I thought you were referring to the built-in `findById` since you are "redefining it". Something like `find` would require some criteria, right? You would need to write that on your own, and figure it out if it returns a single/multiple value(s).

Comment: What is the behavior you expect from Optional<Player> find(); ?

Comment: Try using @Query annotation and pass your query in it.

Comment: find what? based on what?